Is it possible to get bitcoin address from Jan 2010 that still has balance and never send out transactions?
I need to find an unknown address and all i know is that the address received 2 or more block rewards in January 2010 and never spent the coins, So i have used blockparser to dump addresses from 2009 to feb 2010 then filtered then with a file which contains all btc addresses with balance but i still have one hell of a list.
I need to filter further using addresses which never send out transactions but i don't know how to query that.
Please help.

You can use node RPCs: getblockhash, getblock and gettxout for this. See example below.
First, call bitcoin-cli getblockhash 871951, which will return the block's hash: 0000000000000000000233611afd0d00f1e874d8f962c94bdebf40975432b95e
Then, by using bitcoin-cli getblock 0000000000000000000233611afd0d00f1e874d8f962c94bdebf40975432b95e 2 you will get the block's content in JSON format. You can then use some JSON parser (e.g. jq command-line tool) to filter just the coinbase transaction (which will be the 1st transaction in the tx array):
{
  "txid": "9f71b8f4724ead5fa8521e1511867f599064c55237e374c013a5a30ec99be812",
  "hash": "76e359604e2aab1aa5e47829014f78bcbd0b89bd1ad5065f284b7ea44a2c146b",
  "version": 2,
  "size": 325,
  "vsize": 298,
  "weight": 1192,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "coinbase": "030f4e0d04eeca44672f466f756e6472792055534120506f6f6c202364726f70676f6c642f40398451da2c000000000000",
      "txinwitness": [
        "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
      ],
      "sequence": 4294967295
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 5.46e-06,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "1 3daaca9b82a51aca960c1491588246029d7e0fc49e0abdbcc8fd17574be5c74b",
        "desc": "rawtr(3daaca9b82a51aca960c1491588246029d7e0fc49e0abdbcc8fd17574be5c74b)#p35tdfgk",
        "hex": "51203daaca9b82a51aca960c1491588246029d7e0fc49e0abdbcc8fd17574be5c74b",
        "address": "bc1p8k4v4xuz55dv49svzjg43qjxq2whur7ync9tm0xgl5t4wjl9ca9snxgmlt",
        "type": "witness_v1_taproot"
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 3.20244687,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "0 7086320071974eef5e72eaa01dd9096e10c0383483855ea6b344259c244f73c2",
        "desc": "addr(bc1qwzrryqr3ja8w7hnja2spmkgfdcgvqwp5swz4af4ngsjecfz0w0pqud7k38)#y9upg3rz",
        "hex": "00207086320071974eef5e72eaa01dd9096e10c0383483855ea6b344259c244f73c2",
        "address": "bc1qwzrryqr3ja8w7hnja2spmkgfdcgvqwp5swz4af4ngsjecfz0w0pqud7k38",
        "type": "witness_v0_scripthash"
      }
    },
...

Then, you can extract just the txid and vout.n fields to generate a list of transaction outputs to check, e.g.:
9f71b8f4724ead5fa8521e1511867f599064c55237e374c013a5a30ec99be812,0
9f71b8f4724ead5fa8521e1511867f599064c55237e374c013a5a30ec99be812,1
9f71b8f4724ead5fa8521e1511867f599064c55237e374c013a5a30ec99be812,2
9f71b8f4724ead5fa8521e1511867f599064c55237e374c013a5a30ec99be812,3

Then, for each one you can call gettxout, e.g. bitcoin-cli gettxout 9f71b8f4724ead5fa8521e1511867f599064c55237e374c013a5a30ec99be812 0 and if the result prints anything then the TXO has not been spent yet. If nothing is printed then it has been spent already.
Result will look like this:
{
  "bestblock": "00000000000000000000349653eb5d146e6336ea9a95a7a8bcd3fac852f8c908",
  "confirmations": 4,
  "value": 3.20244687,
  "scriptPubKey": {
    "asm": "0 7086320071974eef5e72eaa01dd9096e10c0383483855ea6b344259c244f73c2",
    "desc": "addr(bc1qwzrryqr3ja8w7hnja2spmkgfdcgvqwp5swz4af4ngsjecfz0w0pqud7k38)#y9upg3rz",
    "hex": "00207086320071974eef5e72eaa01dd9096e10c0383483855ea6b344259c244f73c2",
    "address": "bc1qwzrryqr3ja8w7hnja2spmkgfdcgvqwp5swz4af4ngsjecfz0w0pqud7k38",
    "type": "witness_v0_scripthash"
  },
  "coinbase": true
}


All of this could be easily automated to process the block range you're interested in.

All of this could be done a lot simpler with scantxoutset?

I was looking at that but maybe I misunderstood the docs: doesn't that require you to know which address you're looking for? In that case you'd still have to run getblock to get list of addresses and then call scantxoutset on each.

Never mind, of course.
